# Matrix multiplication using Jblas: Matrices need to have same length

Tags: java, matrix, octave, matrix-multiplication, blas

I am using Java + Jblas (first time user) and am trying to multiply two matrices. One is a 163x4 and the other is 4x1 matrix. I would expect the result of such a multiplication to be a 163x1 matrix. However using:

```
FloatMatrix a = b.mmuli(c);
```

I am getting the error:

> Matrices must have same length (is: 652 and 4)

Now while I assume, that makes perfect sense for the program I am confused. The same multiplication worked fine in Octave (which of course applies some magic). But now for getting this to work I would need to know what kind of sorcery this is?

**EDIT**

So here is what the Octave Documentation says about broadcasting (the sorcery):

> In case all dimensions are equal, no broadcasting occurs and ordinary
>   element-by-element arithmetic takes place. For arrays of higher
>   dimensions, if the number of dimensions isn’t the same, then missing
>   trailing dimensions are treated as 1. When one of the dimensions is 1,
>   the array with that singleton dimension gets copied along that
>   dimension until it matches the dimension of the other array.

So this means I just copy the 4x1 matrix 163 times. Then I can execute the multiplication, but instead of the 163x1 matrix I wanted, I now have a 163x4 matrix. Which for me is strange. What is my solution now?

Comment: Are you sure you're not multiplying vectors? `4 x 163 = 652` after all...

Comment: Yeah but the 4 (rows) x 163 (columns) just indicate the dimensions. It's not the actual "math". Sorry, maybe this was not clear.

Comment: Can you provide the full code with which you read the matrices, etc. Such that one can reproduce (and debug) the error.

Comment: I am afraid not. This is a university homework (note: I am only asking for hints). But the code this is based on, is not entirely mine.

Answer (score 3):

So I finally figured it out. And it's one of those mistakes... It has to be

```
FloatMatrix a = b.mmul(c);
```

The element wise multiplication was the error here.